# RegExp to EXCLUDE strip HTML (FOR SOMME) comments

Tags: php, html, plugin-w3-total-cache, cache, regex

I'm using this function to remove HTML comments from my code to save loading time:

```
// Remove unwanted HTML comments
function remove_html_comments($content = '') {
return preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $content);
}
```

But I also use wt3 cache plugin witch uses this to parse code inside his comment pattern:

```
$buffer = preg_replace_callback('~<!--\s*mfunc\s*' . W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY . '(.*)-->(.*)<!--\s*/mfunc\s*' . W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY . '\s*-->~Uis', array(
            &$this,
            '_parse_dynamic_mfunc'
        ), $buffer);
```

I need to implement fragment caching to exclude some parts of my code from being cached, but that is not possible with the function that I use to strip code commenting because it will exclude all comments...

**Is it possible to exclude all comments inside W3TC comment tags from being removed by the function that i'm using?**

This is how I'm implementing on my theme:

In wp-config.php I've added

```
define( 'W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', md5( rand( 0, 999999 ) ) ); // random "secret"
```

In my template:

```
<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
<?php echo  rand(0,1000); ?>
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try slapping a negative lookahead before the comment match, eg

```
function remove_html_comments($content = '') {
    return preg_replace('/(?!<!--\s*\/?mfunc\s*' . W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY . ')<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $content);
}
```

Comment: I think this could work... Right now, it only excludes from remotion the first part of the comment but doesn't closes it. This is how is outputting: `<!--mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e -->
148<div class="clear" style="margin-top:30px;"></div>` and I think it should be like this: `<!--mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e -->
148 <!--/mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e -->`

Comment: Ah I missed the closing slash - will update answer

Comment: now it stop working... :-(

Comment: Hmm just tried it on `'<!--blah--> asdfasdf <!--mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e --> 148 <!--/mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e --><div class="clear" style="margin-top:30px;"></div><!-- blah wow gosh--> hemm'` and it worked (returning `asdfasdf <!--mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e --> 148 <!--/mfunc db26fe44e57fcb1474e4094247b0252e --><div class="clear" style="margin-top:30px;"></div> hemm`)...

Comment: Maybe this is a problem on my side... I don't have a clue why, but the truth is that it stopped working... I don't know if I have this well explained but the RegExp should exclud all regular HTML comments and left intact all the ones that start with `<!--mfunc mysecuritystring -->` and end with `<!--/mfunc mysecuritystring -->`

Comment: When you say it stopped working, do you mean it craps out? If you remove the added optional slash pattern, `\/?`, does it start half-working again as in your first comment?

Comment: This previous code is working by outputting this part of the code: `<!--mfunc 6a542c37559e014373f28e414e7b5d7a -->
953` Now, it looks like this is breaking the code because it's not ending the comment "capsule" by outputting this at the end `<!--/mfunc 6a542c37559e014373f28e414e7b5d7a -->`. The full (outputted) code should be `<!--mfunc 6a542c37559e014373f28e414e7b5d7a -->
<?php echo  rand(0,1000); ?>
<!--/mfunc 6a542c37559e014373f28e414e7b5d7a -->`. But When you altered the slash pattern to `\/?`, it stopped working at all...

Comment: Ok, I don't understand that, so giving up I'm afraid...